# Cannot read property of null in jest test where child component is being mocked

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have 3 component structured as follows:

```
const Parent = () => {
    // this component uses hooks
    return (
        <div>
            Test
            <Child />
        </div>
    )
}

const Child = () => {
    // this component uses hooks
    return (
        <>
            Other content
            <Child2>
                {stuff}
            </Child2>
        </>
    )
}

const Child2 = () => {
    return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

In my test I'm mocking Child like:

```
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";

jest.doMock("./Child", () => () => <div>MockChild</div>);

describe("Snapshot", () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer
                        .create(<Parent />)
                        .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})
```

But upon running the test I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null`.

Following the stacktrace I can see the error is from the `children` in Child2. My question is, why is jest mounting Child2 when I'm mocking Child in my test? Shouldn't it get disregarded? How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you exported the `Child` component in your `Child.js` file?

Comment: Yes I have exported it

Answer (score 1):

[jest.doMock is not hoisted](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options)

That is why you have to doMock first then import the Component below respectively.

```
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";

jest.doMock("./Child", () => () => <div>MockChild</div>);

// here is where you should import Parent
import Parent from './Parent';

describe("Snapshot", () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer
                        .create(<Parent />)
                        .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})
```

By the way, i recommend you to use the famous [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) instead of `react-test-renderer`. It has Shallow Rendering which exactly does what you wanted out of the box (mock every child component). It also offers Full render and static render.

Comment: I've moved the mock up before importing Parent but now getting this error: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`